# Deregister and Dequeue Stylesheets From a Plugin and Enqueue a Child's Stylesheet/s

Tags: php, child-theme

I'm trying to Deregister and Dequeue 3 Stylesheets from a Plugin (WP Listings) and Enqueue 3 Stylesheets within my Child Theme's directory.

I have tried using the following code, but all 3 of the plugins stylesheet still load before the child stylesheets.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
//* Load WP Listings Style Sheet from Child Theme
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_alta_styles' );

function load_alta_styles() {

wp_dequeue_style( 'wp_listings' );
wp_deregister_style( 'wp_listings' );

wp_dequeue_style( 'wp_listings_widgets' );
wp_deregister_style( 'wp_listings_widgets' );

wp_dequeue_style( 'wp_listings_single' );
wp_deregister_style( 'wp_listings_single' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-listings-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/wp-listings.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-listings-widgets-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/wp-listings-widgets.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-listings-single-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/wp-listings-single.css' );

}
```

Can anyone point out where I could be going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Just try using a later/higher `priority` for `add_action()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kaiser noted, you probably need a higher priority.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_alta_styles', 20 );
```

But if not, you can use [wp_style_is](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is) to check and see after you do things if they are as expected.

e.g. you might try:

```
if ( wp_style_is( 'wp_listings_single', 'enqueued' ) ) {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'wp_listings_single' );
   echo '<p>Seems to have been dequeued</p>';
   if ( wp_style_is( 'wp_listings_single', 'enqueued' ) ) {
       echo '<p>But actually was not</p>';
   }
} else {
   echo '<p>wp_listings_style was not actually enqueued ... </p>';
}
```